# How to setup CardDAV and CalDAV in Apache Server?

Tags: apache, synchronization, caldav, carddav

If my question is stupid, I'm sorry, I'm a newbie, and totally have no idea if that's possible or something.

I have already set up my personal `http server`, including `webdav`, using `apache` and `tomcat` on my PC, so that my `android` and `ios` devices can get access to my computer and do some data transfer with my pc wirelessly.

And after trying the Thunderbird, it suddenly came to me, if I can set up my private contact and calendar server, so that my devices can sync those contacts and events with my own server.
 And I can not find such tutorials.

So, How to setup CardDAV and CalDAV in Apache Server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take a look at [mod_caldav](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~jimc/documents/pimstuff/mod_caldav-inst.html) and [mod_carddav](http://modcarddav.sourceforge.net), but they seem to be stuck in very early states (v0.2.0/v0.0.1) . It's probably better to pick a specialized [CalDAV](https://devguide.calconnect.org/CalDAV/Server-Implementations/) or [CardDAV](https://devguide.calconnect.org/CardDAV/Server-Implementations/) server. E.g. I would recommend [CalendarServer](http://www.calendarserver.org), but there are other choices. Just check the list and find one which works for you.

Comment: mod_caldav and mod_carddav seems to be complete now

Comment: That comment by @Antonio is unsubstantiated. the mod_caldav and mod_carddav projects linked by hnh (source on SourceForge) haven't been updated in a decade. Unless there are other projects by the same name?

Answer (score 0):

Solving the similar problem, I finally ends up with **radicale** caldav server running through mod_wsgi.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want to look at open source projects like

- https://owncloud.com/
- https://nextcloud.com/

The allow WebDEV, CardDAV, CalDAV and other services just common to clouds, and you can synchronize your data from Outlook, Evolution, mobiles etc.

Despite the fact they implement what you have done already they can serve multiple users and have UI support to choose with which user to share what data. Not to talk about various other addons...